# javascript: convert number to time

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two numbers which represent the startHour and endHour

```
let startHour = 1530;
let endHour = 1700;
```

I tried to get the diff between the two times, with the below code i get 1.5 as result, but is not significant

```
let startHour = new Date(null);
startHour.setHours(+element.startHour.toString().substring(0, 2));
startHour.setMinutes(+element.startHour.toString().substring(2, 4));
startHour.setSeconds(0);

let endHour = new Date(null);
endHour.setHours(+element.endHour.toString().substring(0, 2));
endHour.setMinutes(+element.endHour.toString().substring(2, 4));
endHour.setSeconds(0);

let diff = Math.abs(startHour.getTime() - endHour.getTime()) / 3600000; // 1.5
```

How can i get the result in the format 1h:30min inside 1.5 ?

Comment: What do you need actually? A different approach to get the difference or just format the answer `1.5` to `1h:30min` format ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with below code.

```js
let diff = 1.5;
let hours = parseInt(diff), minutes = (diff - hours) * 60;
alert(hours + 'h:' + minutes + 'min');
```

Comment: Hi @sapics, Its better if you can parse the minutes to integer, too. Otherwise you can have `1h:21.000000000000007min` kind of a answer because of the division.

Comment: It's true, thanks. If you want get minutes in integer format, please transform `minutes = (diff - hours) * 60` to `minutes = parseInt((diff - hours) * 60 + 0.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to get the result in minutes first:

```
let diff = ((endHour.getTime() - startHour.getTime()) / 1000) / 60; // convert into minutes -> 90
let hours, minutes;
hours = (diff - (diff % 60)) / 60; // count full hours with substracting minutes with modulo operator
minutes = (diff % 60); // use modulo operator to get minutes < 60.
console.log(hours + 'h:' + minutes + 'min');
```